# TwitterAPIExchange suddenly stops working

Tags: php, ajax, json, twitter

So I'm making a Twitter fetch website where all the tweets from a specific hashtag will be fetched in real-time with ajax. It all works fine, I thought, until it all suddenly stops working. If I then wait for 3 minutes or so, it then starts working again. PHP is giving me errors such as

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object...

The code I'm running:

```
require_once '../lib/TwitterAPIExchange.php';

$settings = array(
    'oauth_access_token' => "...",
    'oauth_access_token_secret' => "...",
    'consumer_key' => "...",
    'consumer_secret' => "..."
);

$url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json';
$getfield = '?q=#hashtag&result_type=recent';
$requestMethod = 'GET';

$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$response = $twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
                             ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
                             ->performRequest();

foreach(json_decode($response) as $result){
    foreach($result as $post){
        echo '<div class="post"><div class="header"><img src="'.$post->user->profile_image_url.'"><p class="user">'.$post->user->name.'</p></div><div class="text">'.$post->text.'</div></div>';
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you are making requests too fast after each other? So maybe you are experiencing DOS protection.

Comment: Have you inspected the value that PHP is trying to parse? It's possibly an error message from Twitter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with help from @Uwe Allner. It turned out the Twitter API has something called API Rate Limits. So, as you may guess, they are limiting the amount of requests per x time. Under "Search", I noticed they have set a limit at 180 queries per 15 minutes. So I can make a query each 5 seconds.

```
180/15 = 12
60/12 = 5
```